# Sql Trigger - multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, triggers

I'm trying to get info from 1 table and insert it into a record on another table. But I keep getting this error every time I try to use the WHERE clause. I need the WHERE because I need the value from the first table to be in the same record in the second table with the same Quote Number.

My Code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsertQuoteNumber
ON AccountInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ShippingIdentity nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @QuoteNumber nvarchar(50)
SELECT @QuoteNumber = QuoteNumber FROM AccountInfo

BEGIN
UPDATE ShippingInfo SET @QuoteNumber = QuoteNumber 
WHERE AccountInfo.ShippingIdentity =  ShippingInfo.ShippingIdentity
END
```

Comment: what is the dbms being used?

Comment: Make sure you have a great backup before you run that code.

Comment: This is typical XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting this error every time I try to use the WHERE clause.

The error is here:

```
UPDATE ShippingInfo SET @QuoteNumber = QuoteNumber 
WHERE AccountInfo.ShippingIdentity --AccountInfo is not a part of query
=  ShippingInfo.ShippingIdentity
```

In fact, you are in luck else you will update all rows. Your trigger should be something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsertQuoteNumber
ON AccountInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
--may make sense if you guarantee single row insert only
--DECLARE @ShippingIdentity nvarchar(50)
--DECLARE @QuoteNumber nvarchar(50)
--From What Row?
--SELECT @QuoteNumber = QuoteNumber FROM AccountInfo

BEGIN
UPDATE ShippingInfo SET QuoteNumber = i.QuoteNumber 
from ShippingInfo s 
inner join inserted i on s.ShippingIdentity = i.ShippingIdentity 
--no **where** required
--WHERE AccountInfo.ShippingIdentity =  ShippingInfo.ShippingIdentity
END
```

Comment: (In fact, you are in luck else you will update all rows...)      That is why you need a great backup.  The original poster is in great luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I insert my values from my website the QuoteNumber on the ShippingInfo table is NULL. But If I re run the form without refreshing my page the QuoteNumber gets inserted into a column that shouldn't have that particular QuoteNumber in. Should there be code where you committed out my code?

Comment: This is different question. Did I answer the question you asked initially? Your last comment sounds like  [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually, After I took a closer look I think your code is good but I think I wasn't clear on what I'm trying to do. I need to get the QuoteNumber from a table called AccountInfo and insert it into a table called ShippingInfo on the same record where the ShippingIdentity matches. Thats why I was trying to use the WHERE clause. Maybe Update isn't exactly the right way to go. Thanks for your replies

Comment: If your `QuoteNumber` first appear in `ShippingInfo` then you need trigger on  ShippingInfo after update which insert or update value in your another table.

Comment: QuoteNumber appears in AccountInfo first, then I'm trying to insert it into ShippingInfo with the same ShippingIdentity in both tables

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this wrong again but I'm trying to modify your code some but I keep getting an error whenever I try to get the 2 tables to match up ShippingIdentity                                                                            ALTER TRIGGER InsertQuoteNumber
ON AccountInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ShippingInfo (QuoteNumber)
SELECT a.QuoteNumber 
FROM INSERTED as a
inner join inserted  on ShippingIdentity = a.ShippingIdentity

Comment: If matching record exists in ShippingInfo then my code updates it. If record doesn't exist then change (or add) `update ShippingInfo set... ` to `insert ShippingInfo fld1,fld2 select ... from inserted`

Comment: I get an error on the ShippingIdentity = a.ShippingIdentity